# A Proof of Concept for P2P Bitcoin Exchange?

Tags: marketplace

Has anyone proposed or developed a proof of concept for a P2P bitcoin exchange?

Edit:

Let me add some layers here. How would trust work in a P2P exchange? How would one actually get the money they have exchanged for? Does this require a bank to be involved?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check NashX project. It's anonymous online Person-to-Person cash exchange that uses Mutually assured destruction to create Nash equilibrium for traders.

http://nashx.com/

Answer (score 1):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=172705.0
I believe this is a suggestion for a peer-to-peer bitcoin exchange.